# batch copy files from windows to linux

Tags: linux, batch-file, pscp

I have a lot of linux driven devices which I need to configure and setup. All devices have same root pass. Now I need to copy files on those devices.

One way is using `pscp.exe`, but this utility requires interaction, prompting `The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.` message.

Actually, I don't need secure copy, I just need to copy files in batch mode for any given device without user interaction. How can I do it?

Comment: All devices have same root pass. -> For batch copying, it might be useful to work with keys instead of passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just connect to the server once with putty and accept the server's key, you'll be fine, and `pscp` won't nag you afterwards.

Other options would be a writable smb share ( or nfs if you fancy that) , an ftp server, ...

Comment: hehe, I see where this is going to be a problem then :p. Well, I'd go for the ftp server approach then. ftp servers are generally easy to setup in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

With help of `plink.exe` it is possible with simple:

```
echo y | "PLINK.EXE"  -pw pass user@%ip% echo foobar > nul 2>&1 || goto myError
```

Now I can use `pscp` without worry that it will request undesired interaction.